# MVC Post and Put mapping methods, response body values "null" but status 200 OK using Post Man

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, post, put

I'm trying to do an application using Spring Boot MVC and I've run into a problem. For the Post and Put methods I receive status 200 ok but the values are "null". The new registration on database is created but just the Id (autoincrement) column is populated and received in Postman response. Could someone help me please?

`    @RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
public class ExtractedNumbersController {
private final ExtractedNumbersService extractedNumbersService;
@Autowired
public ExtractedNumbersController(ExtractedNumbersService extractedNumbersService) {
this.extractedNumbersService = extractedNumbersService;
}

```
    @PostMapping("/addExtractedNumbers")
    public ExtractedNumbers addExtractedNumbers(@RequestBody ExtractedNumbers extractedNumbers) {
        return extractedNumbersService.addExtractedNumbers(extractedNumbers);
    }


    @GetMapping("/findAllExtractedNumbers")
    public List<ExtractedNumbers> findAllActivities() {
        return extractedNumbersService.findAllExtractedNumbers();
    }

    @GetMapping("findExtractedNumbersById/{id}")
    public Optional<ExtractedNumbers> findExtractedNumbersById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return extractedNumbersService.findByIdExtractedNumbers(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/updateExtractedNumbers/{id}")
    public ExtractedNumbers updateProduct(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody ExtractedNumbers extractedNumbers) {
        Optional<ExtractedNumbers> extractedNumbersFromDatabase = extractedNumbersService.findByIdExtractedNumbers(id);
        if (extractedNumbersFromDatabase.isPresent()) {
            extractedNumbersFromDatabase.get().setExtractedNumbers(extractedNumbers.getExtractedNumbers());
            extractedNumbersFromDatabase.get().setExtractionDate(extractedNumbers.getExtractionDate());
            final ExtractedNumbers updatedExtractedNumbers = extractedNumbersService.addExtractedNumbers(extractedNumbersFromDatabase.get());

            return updatedExtractedNumbers;
        }
        return extractedNumbersService.addExtractedNumbers(extractedNumbers);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deleteExtractedNumbersById/{id}")
    public void deleteExtractedNumbersById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        extractedNumbersService.deleteExtractedNumbers(id);
    }

}



@Data
@Table
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExtractedNumbers {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer extractedNumbersId;
    @Column
    private String extractedNumbers;
    @Column
    private String extractionDate;

    public ExtractedNumbers(String extractedNumbers, String extractionDate) {
        this.extractedNumbers = extractedNumbers;
        this.extractionDate = extractionDate;
    }

    public String getExtractedNumbers() {
        return extractedNumbers;
    }

    public void setExtractedNumbers(String extractedNumbers) {
        this.extractedNumbers = extractedNumbers;
    }

    public String getExtractionDate() {
        return extractionDate;
    }

    public void setExtractionDate(String extractionDate) {
        this.extractionDate = extractionDate;
    }
}


public interface ExtractedNumbersService {
    List<ExtractedNumbers> findAllExtractedNumbers();
    ExtractedNumbers addExtractedNumbers(ExtractedNumbers extractedNumbers);
    Optional<ExtractedNumbers> findByIdExtractedNumbers(Integer extractedNumbersId);
    ExtractedNumbers update(ExtractedNumbers extractedNumbers);
    void deleteExtractedNumbers(Integer extractedNumbersId);
}



@Service
public class ExtractedNumbersServiceImpl implements ExtractedNumbersService {
    private final ExtractedNumbersRepository extractedNumbersRepository;

    public ExtractedNumbersServiceImpl(ExtractedNumbersRepository extractedNumbersRepository) {
        this.extractedNumbersRepository = extractedNumbersRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ExtractedNumbers> findAllExtractedNumbers() { return extractedNumbersRepository.findAll() ; }

    @Override
    public ExtractedNumbers addExtractedNumbers(ExtractedNumbers extractedNumbers) {
        return extractedNumbersRepository.save(extractedNumbers);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<ExtractedNumbers> findByIdExtractedNumbers(Integer extractedNumbersId) {
        return extractedNumbersRepository.findById(extractedNumbersId);
    }

    @Override
    public ExtractedNumbers update(ExtractedNumbers extractedNumbers) {
        return extractedNumbersRepository.save(extractedNumbers);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteExtractedNumbers(Integer extractedNumbersId) {
extractedNumbersRepository.deleteById(extractedNumbersId);
    }
}`

[Database][1]
```

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkuRh.png)
[Extracted Numbers Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suz1O.png)

Comment: So the values are present in the database ? But the response contains `null` ?

Comment: Actually no. I send the values for a new User via Postman using PUT or POST method. The new line into database is created but with out values. Values are just in the ID column which is autoincrement :(

Comment: oké the modify your json in Postman to match the casing of your object (remove underscore)

Comment: Thank you MevlütÖzdemir! It has worked.

Answer (score -1):

Are your attributes in ExtractedNumbers consistent with the database table column?
if your table column is like extracted_numbers you need to do the underline to camel

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the problem not comes from there. I've shared with you picture of database table, postman and ExtractedNumbers Class to be more clear the matter. Thanks!